# Turning off android.permission.INTERNET in CodenameOne

Tags: codenameone

At http://www.codenameone.com/blog/androids-permissions.html, it says this about internet permissions:

> android.permission.INTERNET - this is a hardcoded permission in Codename One, the ability to connect to the network is coded into all Codename One applications.

Is it possible to turn this off or override it? The wording suggests otherwise. But I'm writing the rare application that has no need to access the internet. This will be obvious to my users as well. So when my users try to install my application, they may think it's asking for internet access to pass on marketing information. I'd rather not ask my customers for any privileges that I don't actually need.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the build hint `android.removeBasePermissions=true`

This is covered [here](https://www.codenameone.com/manual/advanced-topics.html).